# Form sends <textarea> tag along with the body

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I'd like to submit this form as a Django template:

```
<form action="/feedback" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group">
       {% if form.title.errors %}
       <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> {{ form.title.errors }}</div>
       {% endif %}

       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6">
          <div class="form-group">
           <input id="id_title" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{title}}" >
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>

   {% if form.body.errors %}
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ form.body.errors }}</div>
   {% endif %}

   <div class="form-group">
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="id_body" name="body" rows="20">{{body}}</textarea>
  </div>

    <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="send"> Send</button>
  </div>     
</form>
```

The problem is that the received form body contains `<textarea>` tag like this:

```
<textarea cols="40" id="id_body" name="body" rows="10">
Your site is good!</textarea>
```

But I want it to be:

```
Your site is good!
```

I had tried different tricks like changing textarea class but could not fix it. So appreciate your help.

Update: here is the views:

```
def feedback(request):
    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FeedbackForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():           
            d = form.save(commit = False)
            try:
                author =  get_user(request)
            except:
                author = 'Guest'
            d.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            d.body = form['body']
            d.published = False
            d.save()

            return render_to_response('feedback/sent_thanks.html',
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 


        else:
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args['title'] = request.POST['title']
            args['body']= request.POST['body']
            args['form'] = form
            return render_to_response('feedback/send_form.html', args, 
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))    

    else:        
        form = FeedbackForm()
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form
        return render_to_response('feedback/send_form.html', args, 
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: show your `feedback` view

Comment: @Satendra I added the views.

Comment: make sure there is no `textarea` in `sent_thanks.html`. because you are sending it as form valid response

Comment: `sent_thanks.html` is just an acknowledgment html send back to the user after the form is properly submitted. It has nothing to do with the form's body.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `textarea` wraps the `{{body}}` in the template and add textarea attributes within your `FeedbackForm`.

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = FeedbackForm
            fields = ('body', )
            widgets={'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 20})}
```

Comment: Can you add your suggested html? When I remove textarea and put only `{{body}}` there, it is not displayed.

Comment: remove this line <textarea  class="form-control" id="id_body" name="body" rows="20">{{body}}</textarea> and keep {{body}} tag only. {{body}} tag is already a textarea so you don't need to wrap it with textarea again.

Comment: the result will be like this: 
   <div class="form-group">
      {{body}}
   </div>

Comment: Well, so replace {{body}} with {{form.body}}, I believe is better to use forloop with form.

Comment: Using `{{form.body}}` the textarea appears. But I  still get the tag in the views.

Comment: I have looked at the code many times, try to get cleaned data from form body. change the following line `d.body = form['body']` to be `d.body = form.cleaned_data['body']` I think this is the reason

Answer (score -1):

I think problem is somewhere inside view not template. Debug body variable.

Or post where template is loaded.

Comment: The views is fine. The problem arose when I tried to 'beautify' the form with bootstrap classes. Before that it received the forms body as expected.